# Screen flashes when loading new scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a level selection menu, inside this I have buttons to load my scene levels.

I am using the next method to switch the scenes:

```
UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene();
```

The problem is that I have dark-gray faders in my scene and when I load the different scenes the screen flashes white. Instead of staying in the same dark-gray tone like I would want it.

I will gladly supply any further information that you need.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Can you explain more about the faders; are they planes in front of your camera or something?

Comment: @Absinthe They are Solid Color Images on my Canvas.

Comment: Look up loading screens. It might help explain what you're experiencing. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/make-loading-screen-unity And give you ideas for a solution.

Comment: @ChuckSavage I took a look at it, thanks :) But my problem lies somewhere else: In the time that unity opens the new scene, but it is still not loaded, the screen just shows blank white.

Comment: @IanH. The last frame of the previous scene is contiguous with the first frame of the next scene, so is there anything that could change or disable your fader image in either of those two frames?

Comment: @Absinthe Oh my god I can't believe myself. After fading in the fader image I assigned a solid white to it instead of the gray that I wanted. Thanks alot!

Comment: @IanH. Great, glad we solved it. I'll post the answer for anyone else needing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last frame of the previous scene is contiguous with the first frame of the next scene so one needs to ensure that there is nothing in either frame that could make a visible difference e.g. resetting the state of something like a material colour via a script called from an Awake function.